# DBPedia SPARQL <LONG::IRI_RANK>

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, pagerank, sesame

I could run SRARQL queries with  LONG::IRI_RANK from this URL: http://dbpedia.org/sparql but I can't run it in my local OpenRDF Sesame repository loaded with 'person_en.nt' DBPedia dataset file(SPARQL parser error).

Is it possible to use LONG::IRI_RANK (or something similar) for the local Sesame repository(not Virtuoso)? May be I should load another(which one?) DBPedia dataset file into my local Sesame repository?
Thanks!

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX+rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+vrank%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvoc%2Fvrank%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fs+%3Fv+%0D%0AFROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E+%0D%0AFROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpeople.aifb.kit.edu%2Fath%2F%23DBpedia_PageRank%3E+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3AUniversity.%0D%0A%3Fs+vrank%3AhasRank%2Fvrank%3ArankValue+%3Fv.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC%28%3Fv%29+LIMIT+50%0D%0A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IRI_RANK` is a proprietary extension in OpenLink Virtuoso. To the best of my knowledge, nothing comparable is available in Sesame.

Comment: out of curiosity: what does this extension do, exactly? A quick search didn't result in any documentation for it...

Comment: It ranks IRIs somehow. I'm not sure by what. Didn't find any documentation either.

Comment: Documentation for entity ranking in Virtuoso is available here: http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtuosoFacetsViewsLinkedData#Entity%20Ranking